# Non-www links are not redirecting to www when directly access non-www.host/request_params

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I am having issues redirecting non-www to www via .htaccess. Non-www links are not redirecting to www when directly access non-www.host/request_params. For example I want to redirect `examplehost.com/param1/param2` to `www.examplehost.com/param1/param2`, but the url `examplehost.com/param1/param2` redirects to `www.examplehost.com/index.php`.

I am using the code below for redirecting all non-www to www links in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please give me suggestion to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your directives could be simplified, but they look as if they should work. Do you have other directives in your .htaccess file that are perhaps conflicting? Add the contents of your .htaccess file if you do.

Comment: What if you replace `[R=301,L]` by `[R=301,L,QSA]` ?

Comment: @ben The `QSA` flag would only be required if you were explicitly appending a query string in the `RewriteRule` substitution. But there is no query string in the example anyway.

Comment: @w3d Thanks for the info, i didn't know that obviously